# Silex\WebTestCase giving Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext class is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0

Tags: silex, symfony

Here is the test class

```
class CampaignControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = CommonFunction::getApplication();
        $app['debug'] = true;
        $app['exception_handler']->disable();

        $app['session.storage'] = $app->share(function() {
            return new MockArraySessionStorage();
        });

        $app['session.test'] = true;

        return $app;
    }

    public function testInitialPage()
    {
        $client = $this->createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertEquals(1,1);
    }
}
```

When phpUnit getting this error, any idea how to fix it ?

```
    There was 1 error:

1) CampaignControllerTest::testInitialPage
The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext class is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage or Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker instead.

/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/symfony/security/Core/SecurityContext.php:14
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php:76
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:126
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:83
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php:327
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:126
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:83
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php:252
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php:264
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:126
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:83
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php:113
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:126
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:83
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php:540
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php:188
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php:538
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:327
/home/ariful1/imoney/formapply/tests/FormApply/Test/Controller/CampaignControllerTest.php:26
```

i am using silex 1.2.x and phpunit 4.3.* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue popped-up in the symfony framework last year. The [final solution](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/13032) was to bootstrap a new error handler that captures deprecation errors when running tests. You could adopt the same solution or otherwise configure your error reporting while testing to ignore `E_USER_DEPRECATED` errors.

Comment: adding 'error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);' to test bootstrap working.